# Remove Custom Post Category In Wordpress Slug Using .Htaccess

Tags: php, categories, theme-development

I am battling for days now to remove a custom post slug from Wordpress permalink.

My theme Category permalink looks like this: example.com/**listing-category**/category

I want to get rid of the custom **listing-category**.

My permalink should look like this instead: example.com/category

I need this format: example.com/sports

NOT

example.com/listing-category/sports

Comment: this cannot be done via HTAccess. You can use HTAccess to redirect the URL to the version that does not contain `listing-category` but WordPress will redirect you back as that is not the canonical URL, the links on your site will still contain the URL, and the header tag will not match as its canonical URL tag will still contain it. If you removed the redirect and canonical tag then Google would penalise you for duplicating content. HTAccess is not the solution to your problem, you need permalink/rewrite rule help not Apache/HTAccess help

Comment: Please, can you help me with the permalink rewrite rule that will only affect that listing-category ??